# JFrame force EXIT_ON_CLOSE no matter what the program do

Tags: java, swing, jframe, thread-sleep

i have a jframe with `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`.
On this JFrame i'm continuously doing calculations by importing API Data etc with the mothod `getBestFlipProfit()` (it's  at the bottom).
The result is displayed on the Frame every 3 or 4 minutes ( importing take long time ).

My problem is that i can't close the frame when the program is in `getBestFlipProfit()`

JFrame method who call the `getBestFlipProfit()` :

```
private void containtRefresher(){
    int delay = 100; // in milliseconds
    ActionListener taskPerformer = evt -> {
        Executor.getBestFlipProfit();
        String res = "<html>";
        for (String key: Executor.best_flips.keySet()) {
            res += DataManager.get_item_name(key) + " profit = " + 
            Executor.best_flips.get(key).get("profit") + "<br>";
        }
        bestflips.setText(res + "</html>");
    };
    new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
}
```

`getBestFlipProfit()` method :
You can see `Thread.sleep(70);` in the `try` i think the problem come from this but i'm not 100% sure, but i can't remove it because then i will have an error while importing API data `429 Too Many Requests` ( = doing requests too fast)

Just saying: there is certainly a way to optimize the code but that is not the purpose of the post

```
public static void getBestFlipProfit(){
    List<String> item_list = new ArrayList<>(DataManager.items_names.keySet());
    DecimalFormat doubleformat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    doubleformat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);
    String t; double buy_price; double sell_price; int buy_amount; int sell_amount;
    for( String item_id : item_list) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(70);
            t = JsonReader.readJsonFromUrl("https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/
                bazaar/product?key="+ api_key +"&productId=" 
                + item_id ).toString();
            if(t == null) continue;
            JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(t);
            buy_amount = root.getAsJsonObject().get("product_info")
                .getAsJsonObject().get("quick_status")
                .getAsJsonObject().get("buyVolume").getAsInt();
            sell_amount = root.getAsJsonObject().get("product_info")
                .getAsJsonObject().get("quick_status")
                .getAsJsonObject().get("sellVolume").getAsInt();
            if( buy_amount < minimum_amount || sell_amount < minimum_amount ) continue;
            buy_price = root.getAsJsonObject().get("product_info").getAsJsonObject()
                .get("buy_summary").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject()
                .get("pricePerUnit").getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsDouble();
            sell_price = root.getAsJsonObject().get("product_info").getAsJsonObject()
                .get("sell_summary").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject()
                .get("pricePerUnit").getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsDouble();
        } catch (Exception e) { continue; }
        double profit = new BigDecimal(sell_price - buy_price)
            .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
        if( !best_flips.containsKey(item_id) ) {
            LinkedHashMap<String, Double> item_info = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            item_info.put("profit", profit);
            item_info.put("amount", (double) buy_amount);
            best_flips.put(item_id, item_info);
        } else {
            best_flips.get(item_id).replace("profit", profit);
            best_flips.get(item_id).replace("amount", (double)buy_amount);
        }
    }
    LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Double>> map = best_flips.entrySet()
        .stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(e->e.getValue().get("profit")))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
        (a,b)->b, LinkedHashMap::new));
    LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Double>> res = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    List<String> listKeys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    ListIterator<String> iterator = listKeys.listIterator( listKeys.size() );
    int i = 5;
    while(iterator.hasPrevious() && i>=0 ){
        res.put( listKeys.get(iterator.previousIndex()), map.get( iterator.previous()));
        i--;
    }
    best_flips = res;
}
```

Comment: Try to run `getBestFlipProfit()` in a new thread to make it asynchron

Comment: Don't use a swing timer, that causes the action to be executed on the EDT. Use an executor service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scheduled executor service.

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

private void containtRefresher(){
    int delay = 100; // in milliseconds
    Runnable taskPerformer = () -> {
        Executor.getBestFlipProfit();
        String res = "<html>";
        for (String key: Executor.best_flips.keySet()) {
            res += DataManager.get_item_name(key) + " profit = " + 
            Executor.best_flips.get(key).get("profit") + "<br>";
        }
        String html = res + "</html>";
        EventQueue.invokeLater( ()-> bestflips.setText(html) );
    };
    ses.scheduleAtFixedRate​(taskPerformer, delay, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

That should be similar to what you've done, but it won't block the EDT. When you close your JFrame, the application should exit terminating the ExecutorService while at it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, i just had to change the `getBestFlipProfit` method like this :

```
private void containtRefresher(){
    while(true) {
        Executor.getBestFlipProfit();
        String res = "<html>";
        for (String key: Executor.best_flips.keySet()) {
            res += DataManager.get_item_name(key) + " profit = " + Executor.best_flips.get(key).get("profit") + ", amount = " + Executor.best_flips.get(key).get("amount") + "<br>";
        }
        bestflips.setText(res + "</html>");
        this.panel.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: You changed 'containtRefresher` not `getBestFlipProfit`. Also, it isn't clear why you would need to call `revalidate` and when you change swing components you should do it from the EDT.